# How can I set the transparency key for a Windows hwnd in Python?

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I'm looking to make the background of my wxPython window (and only the background) transparent.

In Windows, forms can have a [transparency key.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx) This allows the user to give windows "transparent" backgrounds, by setting the background to the transparency key color.

There doesn't appear to be an option to do this in wx. Given my window's HWND, how can I set this directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Murphy's Law, I found the answer right after asking.

The win32gui module has a function to set a transparency key.

**[win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32gui__SetLayeredWindowAttributes_meth.html)**

---

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, Key, Alpha, Flags)

    Sets the opacity and transparency color key of a layered window.

Parameters

    hwnd : PyHANDLE

        handle to the layered window

    Key : int

        Specifies the color key. Use win32api::RGB to generate value.

    Alpha : int

        Opacity, in the range 0-255

    Flags : int

        Combination of win32con.LWA_* values
```